# How do I create a desired (large) Covariance/Correlation matrix?

Tags: matlab, statistics, finance, covariance, correlation

I am doing a project which among other things consist of making time series where one of the stochastic parts of the time evolution of multiple series has a specific covariance. The problem is that a lot of my project demands that I have at least a certain amount of control when it comes to how the covariance between the different time series look, and I have figured out no way of (with relative speed) finding covariance matrices at all as soon as the size surpasses ~30.

**So to sum up:**
I want to make symmetric matrices with n~50 that have desired numbers in certain places, zero in others and are positive semi-definite (MATLABs cholcov only demands semidefiniteness, fortunately).

I Sincerely hope that someone out there has at least an idea!

//Niffe

PS: I've worked in MATLAB so far, but am open to other languages, and also to solutions  in nothing but math.

Comment: @Niffe What does your input look like? Just a vector with signals over time? Or two signals to correlate? Or something else?

Comment: @Marnix- The covariances are going to be used for creating lévy-process timeseries, so before I have the covariancematrices I basically don't have an input. But when i have figured out the best way of creating the matrices I will be Choleskyfactoring them and multiplying them with multivariate normal distributions.

Comment: @Niffe: ok I do know how to obtain covariances and all, but creating them by hand, will still need input right? You can't just create a cov-matrix out of nothing? I think I can't help you then ;)

Comment: @Niffe: Your question and comments aren't clear.  Are you trying to *calculate* the sample covariance matrix of some actual data, or are you trying to *generate* random data with a specific covariance?  I assume you realise that calculating sample covariance is simply a case of multiplying your vector time series by its own transpose?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth  I am trying to generate random data with a specific covariance. Calculating covariances id of course a piece of cake, however generating data with a specific desired covariance structure has proven much more difficult.

Comment: @Marnix: Well, yeah, I need an input which in this case will be my desired covariance structure. So in a sense I want to create covariance-matrices out of nothing, or rather out of desire for different covariance structures.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want. What do you mean by "desired covariance structure"? Do you mean that some elements of the covariance matrix are fixed and you want to randomly populate the other elements while guaranteeing that the result is positive semidefinite? Are the constraints exact, or do you have some wiggle room? Are you looking for a covariance that is strictly positive-definite (no zeros) or semidefinite? Are the diagonal elements (variances) fixed?

By the way, this question really has nothing to do with MATLAB. You can probably get more/better answers posting on the <a hre

Answer (score 4):

Now I can finally answer I think.

What you want is fully dependent on what kind of distribution you want to have.

For example, you could think of a Gaussian/Normal distribution. If you have your covariance matrix, you could do this, coming from the [MATLAB site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randn.html).

> *Generate values from a bivariate normal distribution with specified mean vector and covariance matrix.*

```
mu = [1 2];
Sigma = [1 .5; .5 2]; R = chol(Sigma);
z = repmat(mu,100,1) + randn(100,2)*R;
```

But of course, you could do any kind of process with this. As I can see in your comments, you want to generate random data. That is this. Generating more covariance matrices out of a covariance matrix makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, this is good! But I want to be able to use this method for 50 different time series, instead of two, which means that I need to have the capacity to create a 50x50 SIGMA which is symmetric and positive (semi-)definite (semi- if I use the cholcov command instead of the usual chol). So the thing I want to be able to do is specify how I want the different timeseries to covary (which is probably not a word, but I think it is clear in the context) and out of that get a covariance matrix (50x50) that I can then take the matrix square root of. I'm really sorry if I was unclear to begin with.

Comment: @Niffe Why shouldn't that be possible? Just create a function of some kind that returns a 50x50 matrix with covariances. So you could even create a gaussian 50x50 matrix of some sort and then use it to create your signal. I don't see why this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Marnix the main reason is that the general matrix that is just fabricated isn't positive definite (imposing the symmetries that are needed for a matrix to be a  covariance matrix are of course trivial). At least that is what I have had problems with so far, or maybe there is something else I have completely missed.

Comment: @Niffe So now what is your actual question that you want to achieve from now? You have your random generator for a Sigma. You need to create Sigma, and you can't because...?

Comment: @Marnix, I think I might have misunderstood you. The problem that I am still seeing is that if I want to use the method above to create random numbers with a desired covariance structure I would need to be able to create, say, a 50x50 matrix that both have more or less my desired structure and is positive definite. Generelly if I try to create a desired structure, even if it is only 10x10, it turns out the matrix that represents that structure isn't p.d, and i can't make any time series with it. So how do you suggest I go about creating the sigma? also: I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Niffe So what kind of function do you want your Sigma to have? Because that will be just a function creating the right values of 50x50 then... Do you have a description of your Sigma?